# align an embedded video in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and I'm creating a project using HTML. I embedded a youtube video and it shows up fine, but it's crossing the horizontal border below it and I was wondering if there was anyway to fix that. I tried aligning it to the top of the page, but that didn't work. Is there any inline CSS I can use?

Screenshot:
[image]

Code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rEUz-mBcGV8" 
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Could you please post the problematic code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ It allows us to see exactly what's wrong and keeps other outside variables on a site from having a potential adverse effect on the code.

Comment: Actually, I figured out my problem. I just needed to put the code for the video above my image. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you can use.

```
position: absolute;
bottom: ?px;
```

Play with the pixels in bottom to see how far up you want it to go.